# Display one item of my choice rather than the whole list items in ajax upon success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got an AJAX code, that does POST reqeusts and displays results upon success. The displayed results are in JSON format and from a different website. The result displays all of the list items, but now I want to display only one item of my choice at the same time, instead of displaying all the items. I've been trying to use the `each()` and `slice()` functions, but I think I'm not using them correctly or I don't have any idea of how to deal with the problem. Please help, I'm new to AJAX and JQuery.
This is the code I have:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    async:false,
    url : "http://brandroot.com/index.php?option=com_brands&controller=brands&task=getbrandsbyuser",
    data: postData,
    type : "post",
    dataType : "jsonp",
    jsonp: "jsoncallback",
    success : function(jsonData){
        if (jsonData.product_display!=='') {

            /**The code below will display all the items under a div="product_dispay"*/
            jQuery('#product_display').append(jsonData.product_display);


            //I want a code that will display one item of my choice at this section.

        }else{
            alert(jsonData.error);  
        }
    },
    error:function(){
        alert('fail');
    }
});
```

Comment: Need more information regarding data structure returned and how this choice is supposed to work

Comment: if 'list' means array, then `jsonData.product_display[i]` should be enough - you choose `i`

Comment: I have tried to put jsonData.product_display[i] but its not working. The dipsplayed result is in html. Below is my entire code:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the contents of the **#product_display** element with jQuery. The API returns HTML data so you can render it in the page, then using jQuery find the data within the HTML and do whatever you want with it.

I have added this code into your original code.

```js
(function($){


  var data = [];

  var creatik = null;


  $('#product_display .business_list').each(function(){

    var price = $(this).find('p a span.price').text();
    var bld = $(this).find('p a span.bld').text();
    var img = $(this).find('.image_area a img').prop('src');

    //How to check each logo
    if("Creatick" === bld){
      creatik = $(this).clone();
    }
    
    data.push({
      price: price,
      bld: bld,
      img: img
    });
  });

  //You can use this data as you please
  console.log(data);
  
  //you can replace the contents of the #product_display container with  the one logo that you want
  $('#product_display .business_detail').html(creatik);
  //
})(jQuery);
```

This is the final code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function getbrandsbyuser(user) {
      var postData = {user: user};
      jQuery.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: "http://brandroot.com/index.php?option=com_brands&controller=brands&task=getbrandsbyuser",
        data: postData,
        type: "post",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp: "jsoncallback",
        success: function (jsonData) {
          console.log(jsonData);
          if (jsonData.product_display !== '') {
            jQuery('#product_display').append(jsonData.product_display);


            (function($){


              var data = [];

              var creatik = null;


              $('#product_display .business_list').each(function(){

                var price = $(this).find('p a span.price').text();
                var bld = $(this).find('p a span.bld').text();
                var img = $(this).find('.image_area a img').prop('src');

                //How to check each logo
                if("Creatick" === bld){
                  creatik = $(this).clone();
                }

                data.push({
                  price: price,
                  bld: bld,
                  img: img
                });
              });

              //You can use this data as you please
              console.log(data);

              //you can replace the contents of the #product_display container with  the one logo that you want
              $('#product_display .business_detail').html(creatik);
              //
            })(jQuery);

          } else {
            alert(jsonData.error);
          }
        },
        error: function () {
          alert('fail');
        }
      });
    }
    jQuery(".image_area").each(function ()
    {
      jQuery(this).hover(
              function () {
                id = jQuery(this).attr("rel");
                jQuery(this).children(".published_content_" + id).stop(true, true).fadeIn('slow', function () {
                  jQuery(this).children(".published_content_" + id).css("display", "block");
                  jQuery(this).children(".published_content_" + id).stop(true, true).animate({"opacity": 1}, 400);
                });
              },
              function () {
                id = jQuery(this).attr("rel");
                jQuery(this).children(".published_content_" + id).stop(true, true).fadeOut('slow', function () {
                  jQuery(this).children(".published_content_" + id).css("display", "none");
                  jQuery(this).children(".published_content_" + id).stop(true, true).animate({"opacity": 0}, 400);
                });
              }
      );
    });
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
      getbrandsbyuser("Sarfraz300");
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="product_display"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I am glad to hear it

Answer (score 0):

This is the code:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
<title></title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getbrandsbyuser(user) {
var postData = {
    user: user
};

jQuery.ajax({
    async:false,
    url : "http://brandroot.com/index.php?option=com_brands&controller=brands&task=getbrandsbyuser",
    data: postData,
    type : "post",
    dataType : "jsonp",
    jsonp: "jsoncallback",
    success : function(jsonData){
        if (jsonData.product_display!=='') {

            jQuery('#product_display').append(jsonData.product_display);




        }else{
            alert(jsonData.error);  
        }
    },
    error:function(){
        alert('fail');
    }
});

}
    jQuery(".image_area").each(function ()
{
    jQuery(this).hover(
    function () {
            id = jQuery(this).attr("rel");
            jQuery(this).children(".published_content_"+id).stop(true, true).fadeIn('slow', function(){
            jQuery(this).children(".published_content_"+id).css("display","block");
            jQuery(this).children(".published_content_"+id).stop(true, true).animate({"opacity": 1}, 400);

        });
      },
      function () {
            id = jQuery(this).attr("rel");
            jQuery(this).children(".published_content_"+id).stop(true, true).fadeOut('slow', function(){
            jQuery(this).children(".published_content_"+id).css("display","none");
            jQuery(this).children(".published_content_"+id).stop(true, true).animate({"opacity": 0}, 400);
        });
      }
    );
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            getbrandsbyuser("Sarfraz300");
        });
</script>

</head>
<body>
 <div id="product_display"></div>
```

The result displayed upon success is in html format.

```
jsonData.product_display[i]
```

has not worked.